# IdentityModel.OidcClient RefreshTokenDelegatingHander

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, refresh-token, identitymodel, oidc-client

I'm trying to use [RefreshTokenDelegatingHander](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/main/src/OidcClient/RefreshTokenDelegatingHandler.cs)  but couldn't find any proper way or sample yet with Xamarin.forms.
Has any one got any success?
Here is what i tried:

```
var options = new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Browser = browser,
                RedirectUri = IdentityConstants.RedirectUri,
                Authority = IdentityConstants.Authority,
                ClientId = IdentityConstants.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = IdentityConstants.ClientSecret,
                ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,
                Scope = IdentityConstants.Scope,
                RefreshTokenInnerHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            };

            _client = new OidcClient(options);
```

and inside my Login method after:

```
_result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
```

I'm trying to use it with following:

```
var tokenResult = new RefreshTokenDelegatingHandler(_client, _result.AccessToken, _result.RefreshToken,_result.RefreshTokenHandler);
tokenResult.TokenRefreshed += OnTokenRefreshed; //This one is never called
```

Any one has any idea? or any example?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples) the sample project?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT it is but just for Login and calling api. No examples for RefreshTokenDelegatingHandler

Comment: OK, does the token refreshed? It looks like the TokenRefreshed never triggered.

Comment: No token never refreshed and TokenRefreshed never triggered.

Comment: Ok, you should find out why token never refreshed? Maybe open an issue in that Github would be help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yeah already did that. Thanks